# Connect stdin and stdout to a socket

Tags: bash, shell, sockets

Imagine a microserver that is listening on some port.  It receives ASCII newline-terminated requests and sends ASCII newline-terminated responses.  Simple.  Easy.

Now imagine a simple script that prints a request on stdout and listens for a response on stdin:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  echo "A request"  # send a request to the microserver via stdout
  read              # block until a response is received from microserver via stdin
  echo "Server response is" $REPLY
done
```

[Of course this script could be written in C or Python or SNOBOL or whatnot, but the point is that it prints something on stdout and waits for a reply on stdin.]

Given that, how would I connect stdout and stdin of this script to the socket / port # that the microserver is listening on?  Assume that I'm running on a Linux-like system.  I see hints that `mkfifo` or `nc` might be parts of the answer, but I've not been able to connect the dots.

Comment: Under [tag:bash], you could use `exec {requestfd}<>/dev/tcp/host/2345; echo >&$requestfd "$therequest";read -u $requestfd theanswer`, but under [tag:posix] [tag:shell], you have to use `mkfifo` and binary *netcat*: `nc`!! I'll maybe post an answer lather...

Answer (score 2):

Bash-specific: You can use `/dev/tcp/` as a magic name prefix that creates and connects a socket.

So:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/servicehost/12345
echo >&3 "A request"
read <&3 response
exec 3>&-
echo "Server response is $response"
```

Comment: Under [tag:bash] you may prefer to use a *variable* to store *auto assigned file descriptor* as: `exec {request}<>/dev/tcp/host/2345;echo >&$request ...`

Answer (score 0):

To connect the stdout and stdin of your script to a socket/port that the microserver is listening on, you can use a combination of `nc` (netcat) and named pipes (FIFOs). Here's how you can do it:

1. Create a named pipe (FIFO) for both input (to send requests) and output (to receive responses). You can use mkfifo for this purpose.

   ```
   mkfifo request_fifo
   mkfifo response_fifo
   ```
2. Modify your script to read from the request FIFO and write to the response FIFO:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   while true; do
     echo "A request" > request_fifo  # send a request to the microserver via the request FIFO
     read < response_fifo             # block until a response is received from microserver via the response FIFO
     echo "Server response is" $REPLY
   done
   ```

Use `nc` to connect the microserver's socket to the request and response FIFOs. Run `nc` in the background to handle the communication between your script and the microserver.

```
nc -l -p <port> < <(cat response_fifo) | while read line; do
  echo "$line" > request_fifo
done > response_fifo &
```

Replace `<port>` with the actual port number that your microserver is listening on.

Now, when you run your script, it will send requests to the microserver via the request FIFO and receive responses via the response FIFO. The `nc` command acts as a bridge between the script and the microserver, forwarding data between the named pipes and the socket.

Make sure to replace `<port>` with the actual port number used by your microserver, and ensure that the script and the `nc` command are running in the background as appropriate for your use case.

Comment: This answer looks ... generated.